# IE11 not updating element visually as result of :checked state change (plus sibling selector, checkbox hack)

Tags: checkbox, css-selectors, internet-explorer-11

I'm using the checkbox hack (well, radio button hack) to control some tabs. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I've noticed that IE11 doesn't update the displayed tab until I resize the window (no media queries involved) or select the element in dev tools' DOM explorer.

To see the issue in action, fire up this test case (http://codepen.io/portable_hole/full/PNJJzz/) and click on the "second tab" text. You'll see the radio button activate, but the lorem ipsum text won't change. Then resize the browser window and you'll observe the text change.

Anyone seen this before? Anyone know a way around it?

Here's the HTML:

```
<label for="tab1">First Tab</label>
<input type="radio" name = "tab" id = "tab1" class="explorer-selector" checked>
<div class="explorer-card-contents">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
</div>

<label for="tab2">Second Tab</label>
<input type="radio" name = "tab" id = "tab2" class="explorer-selector">
<div class="explorer-card-contents">
    Proin non justo vel dui laoreet ...
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
[type=radio]:not(:checked) + .explorer-card-contents {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: So just tested in IE11, works the same way as FF

Comment: Really? Odd. I tried on two different machines here and they both exhibited the same behavior. If you don't mind me asking, what OS are you using? We're on Win7. I'm guessing at this point it's either an OS thing or something strange in my company's default configuration.

Comment: So, in even further weirdness... I grabbed the code I'd put into Codepen and plopped it into the actual page where I was intending to use it, just for funsies... and the issue doesn't occur there. 

¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Even weirder: here, your test case doesn't even redraw correctly on window resizing, unless you resize some unspecified large amount, presumably hitting one of codepen's breakpoints. (Which sucks, because my application doesn't have any.)

Comment: FWIW, assigning anything to any `style`-Attribute further up the tree, even `-ms-sucks:1`, seems to force a re-evaluation.